# angularjs access form element inside ngsubmit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

how can i get access to the form element attributes inside the function that get called on ng-submit ?

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $window, session,$http) {

    $scope.error = null;
    console.log($scope);

    $scope.attempt = function (url) {
        //URL get passed.. but i want to fetch it from the form action attribute
        var data = {username:$scope.info.u,password:$scope.info.u};

        $http.post(ul, data).success(function(response) {
            $scope.error = "welcome";
            $rootScope.currentUser = data;
            session.set('siUser', data);
            $location.path('/dash');
        }).error(function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "failed try again" + $scope.info.p + ' ' + $scope.info.u;
        });
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="attempt('<?=base_url('auth/login');?>')" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="info.u" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" ng-min-length="4" required />
                            <p ng-show="info.u.$invalid" class="help-block">You username is required.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="info.p" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
                            <p ng-show="info.p.$invalid" class="help-block">password is required.</p>
                        </div>
                        <button ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

currently what i'm doing is passing it to the function. but is there a cleaner way to access the element from inside controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, in your ng-submit attribute, ng-submit="attempt('...', $event);?>')" pass the $event parameter. However don't forget to add it to your function as well, like so:

```
$scope.attempt = function (url, $event) {
        //URL get passed.. but i want to fetch it from the form action attribute
        var data = {username:$scope.info.u,password:$scope.info.u};

        $http.post(ul, data).success(function(response) {
            $scope.error = "welcome";
            $rootScope.currentUser = data;
            session.set('siUser', data);
            $location.path('/dash');
        }).error(function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "failed try again" + $scope.info.p + ' ' + $scope.info.u;
        });
    };
```

You will be able to get your angular.element like so:

```
angular.element($event.target);
```

Let me know if this solution fits you

Comment: is there any solution without hacking html ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. But this method isn't so hacky, it's just the event. If you are using a controller there isn't any way to get the element expect for jQuery or document.querySelector();. You could do a custom directive and use that instead of ngSubmit. I think this is the cleanest way to get the element.

Comment: Making a custom directive to manipulate the element is a best practice. Angular best practices state that it's not ok to manipulate DOM outside of directives (eg. via a Controller). So that's why there isn't a "non hacky" way to get the element because controllers weren't ment for that kind of logic.